# How to overlay a heatmap on basic plot in R?

Tags: r, plot, heatmap

[a half football field draw by plot()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhCyh.png)

[image]

And here's how I plot this football field.

```
par(bg="transparent")
plot(0,0,type="n",xlim=c(-50,50),ylim=c(0,60),ann=F,axes=F,xaxt="n",yaxt="n"
library("jpeg")
ima=readJPEG("C:/Users/USER/Desktop/g5.jpg")
lim=par()
rasterImage(ima, lim$usr[1], lim$usr[3], lim$usr[2], lim$usr[4])
segments(35,65,35,40,col="white",lwd=3)
segments(-35,65,-35,40,col="white",lwd=3)
segments(-35,40,35,40,col="white",lwd=3)
segments(14,65,14,55,col="white",lwd=3)
segments(-14,65,-14,55,col="white",lwd=3)
segments(-14,55,14,55,col="white",lwd=3)
par(new=T)
curve(sqrt(14^2-x^2)-3,xlim=c(-50,50),ylim=c(0,60),axes="F",ann="F",col="white",lwd=3)

par(new=T)
curve(-sqrt(14^2-x^2)+50,xlim=c(-50,50),ylim=c(0,60),from=-sqrt(96),to=sqrt(96),axes="F",ann="F",col="white",lwd=3)
par(new=T)
curve(-sqrt(5^2-(x+54)^2)+62.5,xlim=c(-50,50),ylim=c(0,60),from=-54,to=-49,axes="F",ann="F",col="white",lwd=3)
par(new=T)
curve(-sqrt(5^2-(x-54)^2)+62.5,xlim=c(-50,50),ylim=c(0,60),from=49,to=54,axes="F",ann="F",col="white",lwd=3)
box(which="plot",col="white",lwd=3)
```

and I want to add a heatmap on it like the picture below:

[what I expect to plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nj2XD.jpg)

[image]

I have try so many method of plotting heatmap, but the common problem I have faced is that I don't know how to put the heatmap on the football field I plot.
sorry, I am a beginner of R so I think it's the easiest way(overlay) for me to do this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about use `image` function with `add=TRUE`, where a matrix is used to specify the area to add.

Here is a simple (and rather boring) example.

```
## Create raster image
plot(c(100, 250), c(300, 450), type = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "")
image <- as.raster(matrix(0:1, ncol = 5, nrow = 3))
rasterImage(image, 100, 300, 150, 350, interpolate = FALSE)

## Add an area
newarea <- matrix(NA, nrow=150, ncol=150)
newarea[100:140,100:110] <- 3
newarea[100:140,110:120] <- 4
image(x=100:250, y=300:450, z=newarea, add=T)
```

It is important to ensure `x` and `y` in the second call of the `image` function correspond to the x and y limits on the first plot, otherwise the new area won't be seen.